# WPF - Complicated way of displaying something

Tags: wpf, templates, listbox, datatemplate, itemtemplate

I have an Object I need to display in a special fashion:

```
public class Foo
{
    public String GroupName { get; set; }

    public String FooName { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsSpecial { get; set; }
}
```

I need the display to look like so:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| GROUP NAME                                             \/|
|----------------------------------------------------------|
 Normal Name   A   B   C           Special Name   X
 ------------------------          ------------------------
 NormalFoo1    O   O   O           SpecialFoo1    O        
 NormalFoo2    O   O   O
 NormalFoo3    O   O   O
```

Basically, I know how to do a ListBox with a Grouping (so I can group), but I don't know how to split that list into Normal/Special PER GROUP like it's shown. The checkboxes are enabled depending on if a Bar is in the collection or not.

No idea where to start from here.

Answer (score 0):

A `ListBox` isn't going to be able to split the list of `Foo` instances into two sets based on the `IsSpecial` property, you are going to have to do this yourself.

The 'standard' approach here would be to use the MVVM pattern, creating two ViewModels, on of 'special' Foo instances, one of non-special instances, then bind each to your View.